# EF connecting to old DB, even I defined other DB - local SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have on my computer an old DB and a new database. The auto-login (with ".") opens the old database.

In the system (EF 4.8), I need use the new database, so I defined the connection string with the path `data source = NewDB/ blablabla`
but EF actually opens the old database.

How can I define that the default database will be the newest?

Comment: It worked after restarting the computer.